# $X$ $T_3$ and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ cont. open and closed $\Longrightarrow$ $f(X)$ Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

The title corresponds to Theorem 14.6 of *General topology*, by Stephen Willard.

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $f$ is onto too. Then, since $f$ is open, by a previous result it is enough to show that

$$A=\{(x_1,x_2): f(x_1)=f(x_2)\} $$

is closed in the product space $X\times X$.

The author picks $(x_1,x_2)\notin A$. Because of $f$ is closed, $\{f(x_2)\}$ is closed in $Y$ and hence $f^{-1}(f(x_2))$ is closed in $X$ by continuity.

Now we can invoke regularity and thus, there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $x\in U$ and $f^{-1}(f(x_2))\subseteq V$. And here is where I have my problem. Willard says: ''Since $f$ is closed, we can find a saturated open set in $X$ containing $f^{-1}(f(x_2))$ and contained in $V$;''.

How I can prove that? I have tried to use the fact that $f$ is both open and closed; then I have the relations

- $f(\overline A)=\overline{f(A)}$
- $f^{-1}(\overline A) = \overline{f^{-1}(A)}$
- $f^{-1}(\operatorname{int}A)=\operatorname{int}f^{-1}(A)$,

but I don't know how to apply them in a satisfactory way. Since $X$ is regular, I can use that $V$ is closed if I want, so I have tried to apply the above to $V$ when it is open and also when it is closed, but I haven't found any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By contained do you mean strict subset? Otherwise the result is trivial. Also what is your definition of saturated?

Comment: @K.Power. Humm, no, I the inclusion doesn't need to be strict, since $V$ can be considered open. And by a saturated set I mean a set $W\subseteq X$ such that $f^{-1}(f(W))=W$.

Comment: A  saturated set (under $f$)  is one of the form $f^{-1}(A)$ where $A \subset Y$ (see definition 9.8 in Willard).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Isn't your definition equivalent to mine? If $W$ is of that form it verifies that $f^{-1}f(W))=W$. The converse should be true in my opinion, but if I'm right the proof is not so evident.

Comment: It's indeed equivalent, and we can also formulate it as $A \subset X$ is saturated under $f$ iff (for all $x \in X$, if $f(x) \in f(A)$ then $x \in A$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the needed lemma and its proof (by me) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/701338/4280).

The regularity of $X$ gives us $U$ open with $x_1 \in U$ and open $V$ with $f^{-1}(\{f(x_2)\}) \subseteq V$ (as $f^{-1}(\{f(x_2)\})$ is a closed subset of $X$ that does not contain $x_1$), with $U \cap V = \emptyset$.

We apply the linked lemma with $p=f$ and $U=V$ to get an open subset $W$ of $Y$ with $f(x_2) \in W$ such that $f^{-1}(\{f(x_2)\}) \subset f^{-1}(W) \subset V$. (This $f^{-1}(W)$ is by definition a saturated open set, the one Willard mentions in his proof).

I hope this provides your missing link...

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I wanted. I'm sure the linked lemma is what Willard uses (without saying) to construct such $W$.

Comment: The construction isn't that hard: in this case $W=Y\setminus f(X \setminus V)$. @Dog_69

Comment: I would say I have considered that set before to proof some result, but in this momment I don't know where...